# React DOM not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React JS file is below:

The logic behind this:

1.) `CreateTable` renders `CreateColumns`, `CreateRows`, & `ChangeResults`

On the first render, `CreateRows` is empty, but once the component mounts, a `fetch()` call is made to update the rows, page re-renders and I have my table

2.) `ChangeResults`component is loaded which creates an input box. State for `num_of_rows` to an empty string (placeholder, not sure if I even need to do this).

When I input some number into the input field and hit click, `onClick` runs `updatePage`, which calls the function `updateRows` (in `CreateTable`), that then changes the state of `people_per_page`. I have the `console.log()` to verify that this is actually happening, and it prints out as expected.

I thought that since `CreateRows` inherits `people_per_page`, and I'm changing the state of `people_per_page`, it would cause a re-render...but nothing is happening.

Can anyone see why that might be?

```
var CreateTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        console.log('initial state loaded')
        return {
            'table_columns' : ['id','email', 'first', 'last', 'title', 'company', 'linkedin', 'role'],
            people_per_page: 34
        }
    },

    updateRows: function(rows) {
        console.log(rows)
        this.setState(
            {people_per_page: rows},
            function() {
                console.log(this.state.people_per_page)
            }
        )
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ChangeResults updateRows = {this.updateRows} />
                <table>
                    <CreateColumns columns={this.state.table_columns} />
                    <CreateRows num_of_rows = {this.state.people_per_page} />
                </table>
            </div>
        )   
    }
});

var ChangeResults = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            num_of_rows : ''   
        }

    },

    handleChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({
            'num_of_rows' : e.target.value
        });
    },

    updatePage: function(){
        this.props.updateRows(this.state.num_of_rows);
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                Number of people per page: <br />
                <input type="text" onChange = {this.handleChange} />
                <button onClick={this.updatePage}> Update Page </button>
            </div> 
        )
    }

})

var CreateColumns = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var columns = this.props.columns.map(function(column, i){
            return (
                <th key={i}> 
                    {column} 
                </th>
            )
        });

        return (
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {columns}
                </tr>
            </thead>
        )
    }
});

var CreateRows = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            'people':[],
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
        console.log('componentDidMount running')
        this.createRow();
    },

    createRow : function(){
        console.log('starting fetch')
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/search', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                people_per_page: this.props.num_of_rows
            })
        })
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {
                return this.setState({'people' : responseJson.people }) 
            });
    },


    render: function(){
        var rows = this.state.people.map(function(row, i){
            return (
                <tr key={i}>        
                    <td>{row['id']}</td>
                    <td>{row['email']}</td>
                    <td>{row['first']}</td>
                    <td>{row['last']}</td>
                    <td>{row['title']}</td>
                    <td>{row['company']}</td>
                    <td>{row['linkedin_url']}</td>
                    <td>{row['role']}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
        return (
            <tbody>
                {rows}
            </tbody>
        )
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(<CreateTable />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: are you sure your handlers work properly? because you are not using `bind` anywhere

Comment: You need to bind your functions otherwise they won't have access to 'this' and therefore won't be able to set the state.

Comment: seems like `React.createClass` does `bind` automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `<CreateRows />`, `componentDidMount` is only called for the first render, when the component is 'mounted' on the page. After that, you need to fetch new data in `componentDidUpdate` or somewhere else in the application.

Comment: Ahh, ok that makes sense. And I found a loop...just executed 1000 fetch calls...woops